# Printing into a label from Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio, windows

I have an excel sheet with 47 columns and about 100 rows. I have a Windows form application with a text field, a button and a label.

Here's what I am trying to do:

When I paste a number into the text box and click the button, it searches the entire excel sheet and fetches the row and column of where that particular string is in the sheet (row, column). This is working fine. I am ok with the performance. Here's what I'd actually like to do -

After I get where the searched string is, I'd like to go to the 45th column, of that same row and get the string from that cell, and display it in the label.

Here's my code (Nothing I did is working!)

```
string File_name = "C:\\Users\\v-nikken\\Documents\\My Received Files\\Case Wellness.xlsx";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook oWB;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
try
{
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(File_name, missing, missing, missing, missing,
                    missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
                    missing, missing, missing, missing);
    oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)oWB.Worksheets[1];
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng = GetSpecifiedRange(textBox_SRNumber.Text, oSheet);
    if (oRng != null)
    {

        //THIS IS THE LOGIC I HAVE TO TAKE VALUE FROM THE CELL TO THE LABEL
        //AND OBV IT ISN'T WORKING

        int IRPlace = Convert.ToInt32(oRng.Column) + 46; //This is obv wrong

        label_IRMet.Text = Convert.ToString(oSheet.Cells[Convert.ToInt32(oRng.Row), IRPlace]); //This also
        label_scope_sent.Text = IRPlace.ToString();

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Case number not found!", "Please try again");
    }
    oWB.Close(false, missing, missing);

    oSheet = null;
    oWB = null;
    oXL.Quit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Sorry about the formatting. The code section wasn't working for some reason.

Please help!!

Windows 10 - Excel 2016 - VS 2017 - .net 4.6.1

Comment: did you tried `label_IRMet.Text = Convert.ToString(oSheet.Cells[oRng.Row, IRPlace]);`

Comment: Yes, but it shows `System.__ComObject` in the label. Any guesses? Is the code right, according to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range valueForLabel=(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)yourSheet.Cells[oRng.Row,IRPlace];
string labelText=valueForLabel.Value.ToString();`

Comment: Ok, then I had to do `label_IRMet.Text = Convert.ToString(valueForLabel.Text);` And it worked. Thanks a TON!